# Qt - Unknown property transform

Tags: qt, transform, qtstylesheets

Right, I am doing a small project of mine on Qt and while using the style sheets for my `MainWindow.ui`  it dropped me the error of `Unknown property transform`. I have used CSS before and I am somewhat familiar with it but I have not had any problem with doing simple translations, transformations etc.

I am well aware that `transform` is not a standard, yet, used in CSS but I should use `-moz-transform`, `-o-transform`, `-etc-transform` for different browsers.

This is the bit where I am using the transform:

```
QPushButton#zoomButton
 {
     border-image: url(:/Data/buttonZoom_Idle.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
 }
 QPushButton#zoomButton:pressed 
 {
    border-image: url(:/Data/buttonZoom_Pressed.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
 }

 QPushButton#zoomButton:hover 
 {
    border-image: url(:/Data/buttonZoom_Hover.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
    transform: rotate(30deg); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt only supports a subset of CSS for stylesheets for widgets.
You find the details on what is supported (and how different properties are interpreted for the different widgets) in the [Qt Style Sheets Reference Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html).

Comment: So there is no way using the stylesheets to do animations?

Comment: @JoeCarr If it's not documented as supported, it's not supported. The documentation for Qt stylesheets is comprehensive.